# HttpPost with simple form-body string parameter throwing No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type Exception

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, http-post

I am currently trying to use HttpPost to handle a form-body parameter to retrieve some information to edit my backend. I have the function

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/delete")]
    public IHttpActionResult delete([FromBody]Product p)
        {
        try {

            _db.deleteProduct(p.ID);

            return Ok(1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

with Product being a model that i created with the characteristics of

```
  public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

However, when i try to use this method via postman, and a form body value,
I am prompted with this error.

```
 {
"Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
"ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Product' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
"ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Putting p.ID in quotes does not send the ID but the actual string "p.ID" to the method.

Remove the quotes around p.ID

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/delete")]
    public IHttpActionResult delete([FromBody]Product p)
        {
        try {

            _db.deleteProduct(p.ID);

            return Ok(1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh yes my apologies. I did not mean to put the quotes. The error is still persistent without quotes as well.

Comment: its a stored procedure that i have wrote on SQL. If i manually add a parameter into the function, ie _db.deleteProduct("00002024"), The data base seems to be handling the stored procedure fine.

Comment: Have a look at this post. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/652633/ASP-NET-WebApi-MultipartDataMediaFormatter

Comment: This post actually didnt seem to help with my problem. I am still getting the same exception. Thank you for your suggestion though. Very much appreciated